# How to make an asynchronous request with angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am pretty new with ionic2,angular2 and typeScript.
I am trying to set up an ionic login page which retrieves login credentials and contact the remote api for authentication via an AuthService.
The sequence diagram looks like:

```
login.html-----1-----login.ts------2------AuthService-------3-----remoteAPI
    |                   || |                  |  |                    |
    |                   || |                  |  |                    |
    -----6(if error)---- |  --------5--------       ------4-----------
                         | 
HomePage----------6-------
```

About the login page components:
**login.html**

```
<ion-content class="login-content" padding>
  <ion-row class="logo-row">
    <ion-col></ion-col>
    <ion-col width-67>
      <img src="logo.jpg"/>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <div class="login-box">
    <form  #loginForm="ngForm">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-list inset>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Téléphone" name="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="loginCredentials.phoneNumber" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="loginCredentials.password" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="signup-col">
          <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full (click)="login()" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">Login</button>
          <button ion-button class="register-btn" block clear (click)="createAccount()">Create New Account</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

    </form>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading: Loading;
  loginCredentials = {phoneNumber: '', password: ''};
  retrievedData: any;

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {}

  public createAccount() {
    this.nav.push(RegisterPage);
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading();
    this.auth.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(
      retrievedData => {
        if (retrievedData) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.log(retrievedData.message);
            this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)
          });
        } else {
          this.showError("Accès refusé");
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Patientez...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

  showError(text) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
    });

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Echec',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
  }
}
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


export class User {
  phoneNumber: string;
  gender: String;

  constructor(phoneNumber: string, password: string, gender: string) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
 currentUser: User;
 connectUseralias = 'localhost:8080/thravvel-core/rest/users/connect';



  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Authservice Provider');
  }

  public login(credentials): Observable<any> {

    if (credentials.phoneNumber === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
            console.log(`About to process request ${this.connectUseralias }?phoneNumber=${credentials.phoneNumber}&password=${credentials.password}`);
      return this.http.get(`${this.connectUseralias }?phoneNumber=${credentials.phoneNumber}&password=${credentials.password}`)
        .map(this.handleResponse)
        .catch(this.handleError);

    }
  }

  private handleResponse(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);

  }
}
```

When i hit the login button, the log "About to process request ..." is well logged, but the request is not sent, (nothing from the browser inspection network tab!!!), this means the flow fails at this instruction:  return

```
this.http.get(`${this.connectUseralias }?phoneNumber=${credentials.phoneNumber}&password=${credentials.password}`)
            .map(this.handleResponse)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

This is the error is have:
Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage  - inline template:28:10 caused by: A network error occurred

With ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

```
ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError http://localhost:8100/build main.js:52225:13  
PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</<.next http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:33833:65  
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:35343:36  
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:19899:13  
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:19848:17  
Subscriber.prototype._next http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:19801:9  
Subscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:19765:13  
Subject.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:19565:17  
EventEmitter.prototype.emit http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:35335:54  
NgZone.prototype.triggerError http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:36185:56  
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onHandleError http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:36164:17  
O</d</t.prototype.handleError http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9172  
O</v</e.prototype.runTask http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7118  
t/this.invoke http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834
```

I do not know where to begin to debug that, i did spend a precious time on it whitout understanding what's the issue.
Really need help!!

Comment: Could you please add a log inside handleResponse and handleError callback functions? And print out error or res?

Comment: Well, you're trying to send a request to `localhost:8080/thravvel-core/rest/users/connect`. That isn't a valid URL. A valid URL would be `http://localhost:8080/thravvel-core/rest/users/connect`. Also, I really, really wouldn't use GET to send credentials. The password will be viewable in the logs of the server (and proxies, etc.). use a POST.

Comment: ooh my god @JBNizet, you just saved my day, how have i forget the protocol? 
About the method, i totally agree with you, i will change it, thanks!!